# Tufte handout citation style

Tags: citing, tufte

I am using `tufte-handout` template to create a summary note. I am using `natbib` package and found out that the citation is printed on the marginpar and at the back page of the book.

My question is how to remove the citation from the marginpar and make it appear in the back page only?

Comment: If you use `\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout}`, you can then use `\usepackage{natbib}` and it will skip all the tufte-handout-specific bibliography stuff and work as it usually does in article, book, etc.

Comment: Hi @godbyk, I have tried it. It is successfully removed the citation from the marginpar, but the autor (year) name is now printed in themain text. How to make it appear as numbered citation?

Comment: Using `\usepackage[super]{natbib}` or `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` should do the trick. Check the [`natbib` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) for more information.

Comment: hi @godbyk, thanks. It works exactly as I want. I use \documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout} and \usepackage[super]{natbib} as you suggested. Thanks!